# Apple Pay - Recurring Payment

Tags: payment-gateway, applepay, apple-wallet, nmi-payments

I am trying utilize [recurring payments through Apple Pay](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaypaymentrequest/3955946-recurringpaymentrequest). It appears that the payment session is setup correctly. The correct popup appears, indicating a immediate charge and a recurring payment, the the payment is successfully submitted to NMI and the response is sent back to the client.

[image]

**Frontend Code:**

```
function subscribe() {
        var request = {
          countryCode: 'US',
          currencyCode: 'USD',
          supportedNetworks: ['visa', 'masterCard', 'amex', 'discover'],
          merchantCapabilities: ['supports3DS'],
          total: { label: 'Budmember', amount: packages?.Package_Amount__c.toFixed(2).toString()},
          recurringPaymentRequest: {
            managementURL:"https://7d50e9ae5e20.ngrok.io/billing",
            tokenNotificationURL:"https://webhook.site/8bb38a60-be08-47f5-82ba-2bdccc7ec4cf/",
            paymentDescription: "VIP Membership",
            regularBilling: {
              label: {amount: packages?.Package_Amount__c.toFixed(2).toString(), type: "final"},
              amount: packages?.Package_Amount__c.toFixed(2).toString(), 
              paymentTiming: "recurring", 
              recurringPaymentIntervalUnit: "month",
              recurringPaymentStartDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            }},      
          }
        
        //start apple Pay session
        var session = new window.ApplePaySession(3, request);
        session.begin()
        session.onvalidatemerchant = async (event) => {
            const res = await applePaySessionRequest(event.validationURL)
            console.log(res.data)
            session.completeMerchantValidation(res.data)     
        }

        //submit payment to backend
        session.onpaymentauthorized = async (event) => {
          const dataPackage= {
          onboardingStep: '7',
          salesForceId: cognitoUser.salesForceId,
          packageId: packages?.Id,
            billingPackage: {
              first_name: currentUser.firstName,
              last_name:  currentUser.lastName,
              company: "",
              address1: "",
              address2: "",
              city: "",
              state: "",
              zip: "",
              country:"USA",
              phone: "",
              fax: "",
              email: currentUser.email,
          }
        }
        
            const res = await applePayInitialSub(event.payment, dataPackage )
            
            if (res?.data?.success) {
              //update token for new field in the token
              setOnboardingStep("7");
              localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token || localStorage.getItem("token"));
              notification("Membership Payment Received","success","Payment Success");
              handleBillingAddress()
             
            } else {
              notification(res.data.msg || "Card Declined" , "danger" , "Error");
              setLoading(false)
        
            }
            session.completePayment({status: res.data.applePayMsg})
         
        }
      }
```

**Backend Code (Apple Pay Session):**

```
async function applePaySession(req, res, next) {
const sessionURL = req.body.sessionURL
let response = {};
try {
function promisifyRequest(options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request(options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (body) {
          return resolve(res.send(body));
        }
        if (error) {
          return reject(error);
        }
      });
    });
}
  const options = {
    url: sessionURL,
    agentOptions: {
      pfx: fs.readFileSync("./merchant_id.p12"),
      passphrase: "SECRET",
    },
    method: 'post',
    body: {
        merchantIdentifier: "merchant.com.some.app",
        displayName: "NAME",
        initiative: "web",
        initiativeContext: "some.url" // Frontend url as registered
    },
    json: true,
  };
  response = await promisifyRequest(options);
  console.log(response)
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
return response;
```

}

**Backend Code (Payment and Subscribe):**

```
async function appleSubProcessor(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const conn = sfConn();
      const { cognitoUserId, accessToken, email } = req.user.data
      const {billingPackage} = req.body
      const {onboardingStep, salesForceId, packageId} = billingPackage
      const member = await conn.sobject("Contact").find({"Email": email})
      const response = await NMI.getSubscriptionById(member[0].Subscription_ID__c) 

      // PROCESSING CODE!!!!!
      //encodes data object to buffer
      const data = req.body.paymentObject.token.paymentData
      var buf = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data))
      //encodes buffer to hex string
      const hexCode = buf.toString("hex")
      
      //if subscription is present on NMI only charge
      if(response?.nm_response?.subscription?.subscription_id) {
        await applePaymentOnly(member, hexCode, billingPackage, email, res)
      } else {
        await applePayInitialSub(req, member, hexCode, res, cognitoUserId, accessToken, email, billingPackage)
      }
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }

async function applePayInitialSub(req, member, paymentToken, res, cognitoUserId, accessToken, email, billingPackage) {

try {
  const conn = sfConn()
  // const { cognitoUserId, accessToken, email } = req.user.data
  // const {billingPackage} = req.body
  const {onboardingStep, salesForceId, packageId} = billingPackage
  const subsc_data = await conn.sobject("Packages__c").find({"Id": packageId})
  const dueNow = subsc_data[0].Package_Amount__c.toFixed(2).toString()
  

  //Error handling - no package available
  if(!subsc_data || !subsc_data.length){  
    console.log("Error")   
    Sentry.withScope((scope) => {
      scope.setLevel("fatal");
      Sentry.captureException("Internal Error, Unable to get subscription data");
    })
    return res.json({
      success: false,
      message:"Internal Error. Unable to get subscription data"
    })
  }

  
 
  //sends request
  const response = await NMI.applePayInitialSubscription(billingPackage.billingPackage, paymentToken, dueNow, email, billingPackage.billingPackage.email)
  console.log(response) 

onboarding logic ...
    }
```

**What I have tried so far:**

1. Recharge the initial token. NMI returned "DO NOT HONOR". This indicated that Apple Pay was blocking the transaction. The card didn't have any fraud alert and I was able to charge it with a new token.
2. Set the subscription interval with Apple Pay to "minute" and attempted to re-charge the token after 60 seconds. Again, "DO NOT HONOR".
3. I set the tokenNotificationURL to an endpoint on my server. I tunneled to my localhost via NGROK for https. I was able to call the endpoint via postman. [I followed the Apple Developer Docs.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/merchanttokennotificationservices/receiving_and_handling_merchant_token_notifications) But didn't receive any hook calls from Apple.
4. I did step 3 with my webhook.site pro subscription. Postman call succeeded, no calls from Apple.
5. I searched StackOverflow for answers and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66138846/stripe-use-apple-pay-on-the-web-for-a-subscription) for Stripe. Here it is described that (with Stripe SDK) the paymentRequest comes with a "paymentmethod" listener which should return paymentMethod.id. I attempted to utilize AppleJS's onpaymentmethodselected to get access to the id but I only got paymentMethod: {type: "Credit"} as a response:

   session.onpaymentmethodselected = async (event) => {
   session.completePaymentMethodSelection({newTotal: { amount:"49.00", label:'VIP Membership'}})
   }
6. I decrypted the payment token on the backend. I followed [this](https://github.com/samcorcos/apple-pay-decrypt) guide to create the certificate and key (.pem) files. His package uses an outdated dependency that doesn't work on newer versions of Node. I used [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apple-pay-token-decrypt) to decrypt the token. However, I was not able to charge the applicationPrimaryAccountNumber. AVS seems to be not allowed so providing the zip code doesn't yield a successful transaction either. Below is the decrypted token as well as the NMI response:
   [image]

I searched on SO and in the Apple Developer forums but wasn't able to get anywhere with this. I have been working on this issue for the past 3 days. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear from the question: Are you trying to use the recurring that's built into NMI? Or are you trying to recharge the Apple Pay token yourself (essentially building out your own recurring system)?

Comment: @HPierce essentially both. The way our app is setup, we use the regular NMI subscription plans to charge members on a monthly basis. However, if a member's transaction doesn't go through as scheduled, then he will be added to our "declines" object on Salesforce and attempted to be charged by our task-runner once per day. Once that task-runner charge is successful, the member's plan on NMI is adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Hey - did you ever get this to work end to end?  I am close but did not get the tokenNotification part worked out.  In fact I don't even see merchantTokenIdentifier in my payload during payment.

Comment: Hey @digidigo I was able to start getting the merchantTokenIdentifier 3 days after I started sending recurring payment requests.